# After adding login-required in pages.xml styles are no longer loaded

Tags: java, authentication, jboss, seam

In a seam-gen generated application I added the **login-required** attribute, to force a user login. After that the CSS-Styles from richfaces aren't loaded neither in the login page itself nor at the other pages after successful authentication. (The application is unusable)

```
<page view-id="*" login-required="true">    
    <navigation>
    <rule if-outcome="home">
       <redirect view-id="/home.xhtml" />
    </rule>
   </navigation>
</page>
```

I returned to the standard settings in components.xml after I faced this issue.

```
   <drools:rule-base name="securityRules">
      <drools:rule-files>
         <value>/security.drl</value>
      </drools:rule-files>
   </drools:rule-base>

   <security:rule-based-permission-resolver security-rules="#{securityRules}"/>
   <security:identity authenticate-method="#{authenticator.authenticate}" />
```

Seam Version 2.1.2

Any Ideas what I could do to get the Styles back or an alternative to force the user to login on all pages? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seam in Action book says

> The same page cannot be configured in both the global page descriptor and the fine-grained descriptor. In fact, **there can be only be a single page configuration per view ID**.

So i think it occurs because some page shares more than one configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I found that section in the book. Does it mean SomePage.page.xml has a conflict with settings in WEB-INF/pages.xml ?

Comment: @stacker May have. You can create a single Test case by using SeamTest with two settings (one global and the other one local) where both conflit view-id

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS files require login too.  Can you add them as exceptions to your current rule that all files require login?

Alternatively you can just protect all html files.

Comment: Thanks for your repsponse. I know this behaviour, but why aren't the styles delivered after successful authentication?

Comment: Tried forcing the browser to reload completely after logging in?